# Issue on Getting Images URL of the Post Gallery

Tags: plugin-development, theme-development, urls, gallery

I am trying to get the URL of the attached galley into the post on custom page layout called `Gallery Page`. I tried to use the code from Codex at [This Page (get post gallery images)](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_gallery_images). but I am not getting any thing on the page!

Can you please let me know what I am doing wrong?

```
<?php
/**
 * Template Name: Gallery Page
 *
 */

 if ( have_posts() ) {
    while ( have_posts() ) {
        the_post(); 
        function pw_show_gallery_image_urls( $content ) {

    global $post;

    // Only do this on singular items
    if( ! is_singular() )
        return $content;

    // Make sure the post has a gallery in it
    if( ! has_shortcode( $post->post_content, 'gallery' ) )
        return $content;

    // Retrieve the first gallery in the post
    $gallery = get_post_gallery_images( $post );

    $image_list = '<ul>';

    // Loop through each image in each gallery
    foreach( $gallery as $image_url ) {

        $image_list .= '<li>' . '<img src="' . $image_url . '">' . '</li>';

    }

    $image_list .= '</ul>';

    // Append our image list to the content of our post
    $content .= $image_list;

    return $content;

 }
 add_filter( 'the_content', 'pw_show_gallery_image_urls' );
    } // end while
} // end if
?>
```

Comment: First of all there are two `<?php`. Second it's a hook, you are suppose to add this in `functions.php`

Comment: Thanks Robert, sorry the second `<?php>` was a typo and I have used the hook in page before and it was working

Answer (score 0):

Your code is going to cause a fatal error as you have defined a function inside a loop, and therefore are redefining the function at every iteration thereafter. That is part of the problem. Take a look at cleaned up code:

```
function pw_show_gallery_image_urls( $content ) {

  global $post;

  // Only do this on singular items
  if( ! is_singular() )
      return $content;

  // Make sure the post has a gallery in it
  if( ! has_shortcode( $post->post_content, 'gallery' ) )
      return $content;

  // Retrieve the first gallery in the post
  $gallery = get_post_gallery_images( $post );

  $image_list = '<ul>';

  // Loop through each image in each gallery
  foreach( $gallery as $image_url ) {
      $image_list .= '<li>' . '<img src="' . $image_url . '">' . '</li>';
  }

  $image_list .= '</ul>';

  // Append our image list to the content of our post
  $content .= $image_list;

  return $content;
}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'pw_show_gallery_image_urls' );

if ( have_posts() ) {
  while ( have_posts() ) {
    the_post(); 

  } // end while
} // end if
```

Note the Loop at the bottom. You have added a filter to `the_content` but there is nothing in the Loop that would apply that filter, or even print any content at all. You need:

```
if ( have_posts() ) {
  while ( have_posts() ) {
    the_post(); 
    the_content(); // minimum
  } // end while
} // end if
```

Comment: Thanks s_ha_dum, this is kinda working now but instead of getting images in an HTML <li> list I am getting images between <p><a> elements! plus the size are all in width="300" height="225" but I need to get the actual size.